# Copy a string for worker thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have an application with a main thread (UI thread) and worker thread.

The main thread passes a large string to the worker thread which is then performing some work based on the passed string.

During the execution of the worker thread the contents of the passed string can possibly be changed.

Is there any way to copy the string (e.g. in the constructor of the worker thread) to avoid possible surprises and work on that string copy instead?

Would copy() or UniqueString() do the trick?

Comment: As @gabr wrote: there is generally no need, unless you modify the string using pointers (PChar, etc.). And yes, UniqueString or Copy will ensure that you get a unique copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to call anything. Most frequently used Delphi strings (string, AnsiString, and UnicodeString) implement "copy on write" mechanism. If a thread modifies a shared string, a new copy of the string will automatically be created in the thread and this copy will be modified.

If you still want to have a string that is not "owned" by any other part of the code, you can call UniqueString(s).

Comment: Note that COW only works if the modifications are done using RTL functions that operate on those string types (`Insert()`, `Delete()`, `[]` operator, etc). If you modify a string's characters directly via a `P(Ansi|Wide)Char` pointer, all bets are off and COW is broken unless you explicitly call `UniqueString()` beforehand.